# If statements don't work on Tensorflow variables

Tags: python, if-statement, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I tried to program a self driving car in Python and Tensorflow with this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import pyautogui as pag
import time

x_p = tf.placeholder(tf.uint8)
y_p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

weights = [tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,3,32],0.1)),
           tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,32,64],0.1)),
           tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,64,128],0.1)),
           tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([25*25*128,1064],0.1)),
           tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1064,1],0.1))]

def CNN(x, weights):
    output = tf.nn.conv2d(x, weights[0], [1,1,1,1], 'SAME')
    output = tf.nn.relu(output)
    output = tf.nn.conv2d(output, weights[1], [1,2,2,1], 'SAME')
    output = tf.nn.relu(output)
    output = tf.nn.conv2d(output, weights[2], [1,2,2,1], 'SAME')
    output = tf.nn.relu(output)
    output = tf.reshape(output, [-1,25*25*128])
    output = tf.matmul(output, weights[3])
    output = tf.nn.relu(output)
    output = tf.matmul(output, weights[4])
    output = tf.reduce_sum(output)
    return output

prediction = CNN(tf.cast(x_p, tf.float32), weights)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    saver.restore(sess, 'saved/model.ckpt')
    for t in range(5):
        print(t+1)
        time.sleep(1)

    while True:
        x = ImageGrab.grab()
        x = x.resize((100,100))
        x = np.asarray(x)
        output = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x_p:[x]})
        print(output)
        if output < 0.5 and output > 1.5:
            pag.keyDown('W')
            pag.keyUp('S')
            pag.keyUp('D')
            pag.keyUp('A')
        elif output < 1.5 and output > 2.5:
            pag.keyUp('W')
            pag.keyDown('S')
            pag.keyUp('D')
            pag.keyUp('A')
        elif output < 2.5 and output > 3.5:
            pag.keyDown('W')
            pag.keyUp('S')
            pag.keyDown('D')
            pag.keyUp('A')
        elif output < 3.5 and output > 4.5:
            pag.keyDown('W')
            pag.keyUp('S')
            pag.keyUp('D')
            pag.keyDown('A')
        elif output < 4.5 and output > 5.5:
            pag.keyDown('W')
            pag.keyUp('S')
            pag.keyDown('D')
            pag.keyUp('A')
        elif output < 5.5 and output > 6.5:
            pag.keyDown('W')
            pag.keyUp('S')
            pag.keyUp('D')
            pag.keyDown('A')
        elif output < 6.5 and output > 7.5:
            pag.keyUp('W')
            pag.keyDown('S')
            pag.keyDown('D')
            pag.keyUp('A')
        elif output < 7.5 and output > 8.5:
            pag.keyUp('W')
            pag.keyDown('S')
            pag.keyUp('D')
            pag.keyDown('A')
        else:
            pag.keyUp('W')
            pag.keyUp('S')
            pag.keyUp('D')
            pag.keyUp('A')
```

But the problem is that only the else statement fires, even though output has (for example) the value 1.3. I was able to find out, that the problem is caused by the variable output in the if statements, but I didn't manage to fix the problem.

Comment: Your logic is flawed. How can a number be simultaneously less than 1.5 and greater than 2.5? I think you meant `elif  1.5 < output < 2.5:`?

Answer (score 0):

You have problems with your if statement.

```
 if output < 0.5 and output > 1.5:
```

your output can't be inferior to 0.5 and at the same time superior to 1.5. So the if statement is wrong all the time.

The problem is the same for all the other elif

I think you want to write :

```
 if output > 0.5 and output < 1.5:
```

Comment: I changed that but the problem is still there

Comment: You changed all the elif too ?

Comment: Whatever, with the new if statement and if your output (printed) is 1.3, it should go in it !

Comment: But the `else` statement is still the only one that fires

Comment: output is a float ? Not an array or something with a dimension different from 1 ?